# Designating a font in Tkinter?

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

I want to use a font called Myriad Pro Condensed, which is installed on my computer.
If I use `Label(infoframe, text="test", font=("Myriad Pro Condensed", 30,  "bold"))`
It just uses the default system font. Using just the family name `Myriad Pro` works but it doesn't use the condensed version I want to use. How would I go about using the correct font in Tkinter?
Here's an MCVE:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="test", font=("Myriad Pro Condensed"))
label.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use font name:

```
Label(root, text="test",font=("MyriadPro-LightCond",size))
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't `-LightCond`, just `-Cond`, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!