# How to use custom font path in tkinter? Windows ONLY

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, fonts

i want to use a font that is in the same directory with my python program but actually python will search windows fonts folder for it, how should i fix it?

(i want to give my program the font path or import the font to use it in my labels)

for e.g :
here if the font `myfont` located in fonts folder my program will work but if not , it will be shown by the default font.

`from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
my_lab = Label(root,font=("myfont" ,10 )).place(x=1,y=1)`

i have use `font=(f"path/to/font",10)` but it doesnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truly custom font in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993290/truly-custom-font-in-tkinter)

Comment: actually it just says to use photo instead , and because my gui program has a lot of window inside each other i cant use photo in it unless i write it with class wich i dont know how to and actually i dont want to make it editable , you know if  anyone change the photo my program will compeletly change

Comment: ***"just says to use photo instead"***: Have you read the last comment also?

Comment: oh yes sorry , and can you explain how should i use this function i run function `loadfont("path\\to\\font")` but it will come up with a Type Error

Comment: ***"come up with a Type Error"***: Have you obey the comment: **This function is written for Python 2.x.***. Which version you are on.

Comment: I've change it to python3.0 now and it works properly with out any error but when i run my program the text are shown by the default font.

Comment: Did your font show up using: `tkinter.font.families()`

Comment: no it doesn't , it just shoo my fonts that e located in windows font folder and some other

Comment: To verify for sure, compare the output from `.font.families()` **without**  `loadfont` and then **with** `loadfront`. Relevant: [designating-a-font-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971184)

Comment: no difference , i don't get what exactly loadfont() do , and i dont get how to use it , i think im doing wrong , i just call it like this `fontload("path\\to\\font.tff")`

Comment: ***`fontload("path\\to\\font.tff")`***: Should be `.ttf`. Try variants of the arguments `private=False, enumerable=True`

Comment: yes now its working , thank you very much , how should i accept your comment to be shown to others as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: How to use custom font path in tkinter? **Windows ONLY**

**Reference**:

- [SO:Answer - Truly custom font in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30631309/7414759)

  > `def loadfont(fontpath, private=True, enumerable=False)`

---

Change the function to `Python 3`:

```
def loadfont(fontpath, private=True, enumerable=False):
    ...

    # For 3.x, you have to convert the isinstance checks to bytes and str

    if isinstance(fontpath, bytes):
        pathbuf = create_string_buffer(fontpath)
        AddFontResourceEx = windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceExA

    elif isinstance(fontpath, str):
        pathbuf = create_unicode_buffer(fontpath)
        AddFontResourceEx = windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceExW
    ...
```

**Try variants of the arguments `private=False`, `enumerable=True` and make sure you  have entered the font name correctly.**

Run the function `loadfont(...)`, like:

```
loadfont("path//to//font.ttf", private=False, enumerable=True)
```

Comment: yes , actually it've solved and shown correctly but texts size is changed. is it related to compile? its ok without compiling

Comment: ***"is it related to compile? "***: It's common issue that *compiled* versions behave different. They are often missing related files and fallback to defaults or fail in whole. Have you doublechecked, your `.ttf` files packed and used by `loadfont(...` exact the same? Please edit the answer to show your used `loadfont(...` arguments.

Comment: yes they are the same  and they are also ok on my pc but when i run my program on the other computer the problem shown. what should i edit in the  answer you've edited it